# How to set a MS Access DB (.mdb) in JasperSoft Studio (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, jasper-reports, ucanaccess

I have a .mdb database and I'm trying to design a report using JasperSoft Studio 6.3.0 (Eclipse plug-in).

In my Java Application I have used the UCanAccess JDBC Driver to build the connection as JDBC-ODBC Bridge is no longer supported in Java 8.

When creating the Data Adapter, I chose "Database JDBC Connection", and then, as UCanAccess is not in the default list of Drivers, I added the .jar file with the UCanAccess Driver.

Screenshot from the Classpath:
[image: Screenshot from the Classpath]

Then, I wrote the Driver Class in JDBC Driver (note: the standard action is to choose one of the drivers in the combobox, but as I had to add it manually, I read somewhere in the Internet that I must write it by myself).

Screenshot from the Driver setting:
[image: Screenshot from the Driver setting]

When I test the connection, it will stay loading forever and will never end.

NOTE: the database has no user/pass. I successfully connected the database to my Java application (using the UCanAccess Driver); my problem is with the connection to the report.

What can I do? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve my question by myself. I also had to add the four .jar in UCanAccess-x.x.x-bin>>lib to the Classpath (commons-lang, commons-logging, hsqldb, jackcess)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238021) your own answer.